# how do I show up a SSP page in Suitecommerce Denali?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

I follow the training step,

> 1. new a SSP application
> 2. set application folder (include setting applications publisher)
> 3. check the folder in /SSP applications
> 4. build a XXX.ssp in there. (used eclipse IDE, and upload it)
> 5. show up the XXX.ssp file  -->  used

http://shopping.na1.netsuite.com/c.TSTDRV0000000//XXX.ssp?n=1

but, still show up "page not found"

what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path to your ssp folder. It's not the file cabinet folder but the path you set up in the SSP Application definition.

e.g. http://shopping.na1.netsuite.com/c.TSTDRV0000000/path-to-ssp/XXX.ssp